# Basic operations on iterators in Rust in comparison with C++

Tags: c++, rust

In order to learn Rust, I'm rewriting some leetcode solution from C++ to Rust and on this way I struggle to understand how to perform some basic operations with iterators.

A particular good problem in this context is [Data stream as disjoint intervals](https://leetcode.com/problems/data-stream-as-disjoint-intervals/).
The full implementation in C++ might be found [elsewhere](https://gist.github.com/KirillLykov/6f1b580398f8c304377b9851c8eab8e1).
To avoid going into particular algorithm details and concentrate on Rust syntax, I will post part of the C++ code which contains essential operations on C++ iterations which I struggle to translate into Rust:

```
map<int, int> m; // start to end, [x,y)
void addNum(int val) {
        auto next = m.upper_bound(val); // seems that m.range(val+1..) might give what I need
        if (next != begin(m)) { // begin(m) might be equivalent m.iter() but how to compare it with range is unclear
            auto cur = prev(next); // haven't found prev method on range
            int end = cur->second;
            // adds to end of existing interval
            if (val  == cur->second) {
                int start = cur->first;
                end = val+1;
                // merge two existing intervals
                // ...
            } else {
                // ...
            }
        }
        /// ...
    }
```

The question is what are the equivalent operations on iterators in Rust? In particular, how to do `upper_bound`, check that what I've found is `begin`, do `prev`, get values/keys out of iterator.

Comment: So now what exactly is your question?

Comment: @mkrieger1 sorry, I've updated the post to address your question. Basically, how to rewrite the code in C++ so that it works in Rust. Maybe it requires restructuring due to conceptual differences in iterators in these two languages

Comment: How far did you come with the examples from the documentation of [BTreeMap](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html)? Especially `range`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When converting code, you should think less about equivalent *functions* but equivalent *concepts*.

This code appears to find the entry in the map `m` that is at or before the key `val`. Rust's iterators are not like C++'s since they represent a range instead of a pointer to a value. We can use the range `..=val` and get the entry at the end using `.next_back()`:

```rust
fn addNum(m: &BTreeMap<i32, i32>, val: i32) {
    if let Some((first, second)) = m.range(..=val).next_back() {
        // rest of the logic
    }
}
```

<sup>Note: I've moved `m` from a global to a parameter.</sup>

As another example of how iterators are different, you suggest that `m.range(val+1..)` is a way to find the `.upper_bound()`, which is true, but you would not be able to iterate backwards to before `val+1`. And likewise, in C++ you have to check against `.begin()` to see if the next access is valid, but in Rust, access and iteration are one-in-the-same, you simply try to get the next value and it will return `None` if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Maybe I didn't get your answer, but the code doesn't iterate over the map. Instead it finds the iterator pointing to the first occurrence of the element with key > val. Than, if this found iterator doesn't point to the first element of the map, we take the previous element from the found iterator and proceed accordingly. So the complexity of this method is supposed to be `log(n)`

Comment: My apologies, I misread the first `if` as a `while`. I've updated my answer and I used [ideone](https://ideone.com/xXJw1Y) and the [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a5e03022555e95dca6d163322374de9b) to compare them.

Comment: Interesting, you search for the range up to `val` and later go back on this range. This is what should be written in the rust books (patterns of work with different standard things) instead of basics of syntax.